# Redefine a specific instance with ByteBuddy

Tags: java, bytecode, byte-buddy

I'm quite new to ByteBuddy and may lack some points here.

I want to redefine a specific instance or more precise, instances of a Type that are instantiated in a specific class with ByteBuddy.

So if I have a class A which declares a variable of Type C and a class B which also declares a variable C, I want just to redefine the instance created in A and leave the original implementation in B. (e.g. just redefine objects which passes an equals check / object == object)

I tried the following, which does not work because the equals check goes against a TypeDescription not against the object in the ElementMatcher.is() method:

```
Object myObject = new Object();
    new AgentBuilder.Default()
                    .with(AgentBuilder.RedefinitionStrategy.RETRANSFORMATION)
                    .with(AgentBuilder.Listener.StreamWriting.toSystemError().withTransformationsOnly())
                    .disableClassFormatChanges()
                    .type(ElementMatchers.is(Object.class))
                    .and(ElementMatchers.is(myObject))
                    .transform((builder, typeDescription, classLoader, module) ->
                                       builder.visit(
                                               //Bind all necessary attributes here                                                
                    .installOn(instrumentation);
```

Is there any way to achieve that? I didn't find anything regarding to ElementMatchers.

Comment: A class defines the properties and behavior of all instances of that class. That’s the fundamental principle of OOP (implemented with classes rather than, e.g. prototypes). When the class is not final, you can create a subclass with different behavior and replace the reference from A to C with a reference to an instance of that subclass. Otherwise, no, you can not alter the behavior of a single object. That’s not how Java objects work.

Comment: Thanks for the awnser, that was something which i thought would be the truth. In general thats not that worse for me. It just leads me to figure out how the ResettableClassFileTransformer works and why it in my case not works as expected (so how I expect ist to work, think it works as designed). My Question here was more a shortcut to a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can emulate this as we for example do in Mockito to identify if an instance [is a regular instance or a mock](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/blob/f5b9975e9305f596e208d840ea90c483193aadd3/src/main/java/org/mockito/internal/creation/bytebuddy/MockMethodAdvice.java#L96) when the inline mock maker is used. In general, the instrumentation is implemented to adjust:

```
void m() {
  // some code
}
```

into

```
void m() {
  if (MyFramework.isActive(this)) {
    // your code
  } else {
    // some code
  }
}
```

This does however not apply to the matcher, but is something you need to implement in your code. You cannot retransform a class to only adjust for a given set of instances. The idea of a class is to define the shape of any object that is a direct instance of that class.